# Best R regex for intercepting a fragment in the middle of a string?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

How do I construct a regex to detect the entire middle chunk of a string, so I can gsbu it out? Here's an example of what I'm aiming to do.

```
MATCH: enter > shop.christopherspenn.com/test > convert
MATCH: enter > shop.christopherspenn.com/page5 > convert
MATCH: enter > shop.christopherspenn.com/ > convert
NO MATCH: enter > christopherspenn.com/test > convert
```

The goal is to find something like shop.christopherspenn.com/test > and be able to delete it from the string.

I've tried gsub("(shop.christopherspenn.com.*)/ > ","",string) as my call but it's not able to grab the appropriate chunks.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
string <- c("enter > shop.christopherspenn.com/test > convert","enter > shop.christopherspenn.com/page5 > convert","enter > shop.christopherspenn.com/ > convert","enter > christopherspenn.com/test > convert")
sub('\\bshop\\.christopherspenn\\.com[^>]*>\\s*', '', string)
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/5WhtAe) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kHdY4v/1). Output:

```
[1] "enter > convert"                            
[2] "enter > convert"                            
[3] "enter > convert"                            
[4] "enter > christopherspenn.com/test > convert"
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `shop\.christopherspenn\.com` - a `shop.christopherspenn.com` string
- `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.